# UIViewController subclass viewDidLoad strange behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Here is a weird behavior in a subclass of UIViewController in Swift. The code follows:

```
import UIKit

class My_ViewController: UIViewController {
    var birthDate:Date!

    @IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel!
    var text1: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print(#function)
        print("Hello!!!")
        print("birthDate:\(birthDate)")
    }

    ………
}
```

The problem is as described below:

It is possible to confirm within the debugger that the viewDidLoad() method is called but the print(s) inside are not executed, jumping directly from the call to super.viewDidLoad() to the end and we can’t see any crash or error message. Can anyone see why this would happen? I have at this point no clue of the issue.

Comment: What is your question? The code runs and all prints are executed. Birth day will crash in this occurency because you are accessing implicitly unwrapped optional, which is not set (At least now I don't see it being set, maybe you are setting it in segue before.) Also don't use underscores in class names and you should not make the lable variable weak and start the variable name with UpperCase.

Comment: If you read the post it says "the print(s) are not executed". birthDate will not crash because in the real code it is set. But this is irrelevant because even the "Hello!!!" and the #function don't print.

Comment: When do you expect the viewController to get notified ViewDidLoad occured? You probably didn't assign this in Interface builder/Somewhere in code.